# Can't configure taxes on store view level

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

How can I configure different tax rates for products on the store view level?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on the Store View level in default Magento.
Product has Tax Class attribute with Website level scope:

[image]

Please take a look for this extension or similar - https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-tax-per-store-view-extension.html

Looks like it allows to configure tax on the Store View level.